# How can I find the levels of a factor that occurs before another specified level?

Tags: r, loops, categorical-data, levels

I have data on the arrival times of species to food. I want to be able to determine the levels of `breed` that occur before the `breed_jackals` and `breed_hyena` levels for each carcass by using the `got.here` value which is their arrival time.

I only want the order so in the first case for `carcass_336`
I'd get one value for the jackals which would be the `breed_eagles`.

For the second carcass `carcass_338` I'd have 2 levels for the hyena `breed_lappets` and `breed_eagles` in that order. And 3 levels for the jackal because the hyena arrives before it i.e. `breed_lappets`, `breed_eagles` & `breed_hyena`.

I thought `arrivals$breed[arrivals$mycarcass=="carcass_336"]` would work, but it gives me all the levels.

Ideally I'd also like to pick out which level occurs directly before the jackals and hyenas too by using the minimum `got.here` for each. E.g. for `carcass_338` it would be the `breed_eagles` for `breed_hyenas`. Again the got.here value will be useful I think because I've used that to extract the shortest arrival times for each carcass for another purpose with:

```
arrivals[ arrivals$got.here == ave(arrivals$got.here, arrivals$mycarcass, FUN=min), ]
```

Here's my data:

```
arrivals <-  read.table(header=T, text="
who     breed           got.here   mycarcass
167     breed_eagles    102        carcass_336
183     breed_eagles    108        carcass_336
181     breed_eagles    271        carcass_336
134     breed_eagles    284        carcass_336
191     breed_eagles    311        carcass_336
283     breed_jackals   5419       carcass_336
118     breed_lappets   200        carcass_338
198     breed_eagles    219        carcass_338
151     breed_eagles    256        carcass_338
206     breed_hyenas    1759       carcass_338
294     breed_jackals   7948       carcass_338
235     breed_hyenas    10988      carcass_338
215     breed_hyenas    13629      carcass_338
290     breed_jackals   17013      carcass_338")
```

The expected output I'd like would be derived from this and would be the frequencies of these occurrences. e.g. for jackals

```
 preceeding_breed   frequency
 breed_eagles         1
 breed_lappets        0
 breed_hyenas         1
```

Comment: Can you show expected output please?

Comment: @mtoto some summary of the frequency of these occurrences would be ideal as I've no stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get count the arrivals by species prior to jackal arrival. There is probably a cleaner method.  For clarity, I'm only going to show the solution for jackals, but getting the results for hyenas would be straightforward.

```
# for each carcass, calculate the first jackal arrival
first_jackals <- aggregate(got.here~mycarcass,
                           data=arrivals[arrivals$breed=="breed_jackals",], FUN=min)

# tabulate the number of other animals arriving before the jackal
beat_jackals <- sapply(unique(arrivals$mycarcass), function(i) {
        table(arrivals$breed[arrivals$mycarcass==i & 
              arrivals$got.here < first_jackals$got.here[first_jackals$mycarcass==i]])})
```

This returns a matrix with the counts for each breed, including hyenas and Jackals. Now, we drop the hyenas and jackals from the count and add carcass names to the columns:

```
# drop unwanted breeds
beat_jackals <- 
          beat_jackals[row.names(beatJackals) != "breed_jackals",]
# add carcass names to the columns
colnames(beat_jackals) <- unique(arrivals$mycarcass)
```

because `sapply` processed the carcasses in the same order, `unique(arrivals$mycarcass)`, we don't have to worry about misalignment.

To get the order of arrival by breed to each carcass, you can use the following:

```
arrival_order <- sapply(unique(arrivals$mycarcass), function(i) {
                                     unique(arrivals[arrivals$mycarcass==i, "breed"])})
```

This will allow you to pull out the breed that arrived immediately prior to the jackal:

```
sapply(arrival_order, function(i) i[(which(i=="breed_jackals"))-1])
```

Comment: fantastic answer. Thanks a lot. One thing is that the carcass names don't reassign properly. Not really a problem for me though.

Comment: @ManassaMauler If this answer worked for you, could select it by clicking on the check mark next to it. If you have a related question, you could post it and I'd be happy to take a look when I get a chance.